# Automatically forward emails from Google Apps for Business to variable address

Tags: email, email-forwarding, google-workspace

At this point, I have absolutely no idea if what I'm asking is possible, but I figured it's worth a shot to ask.

I need to be able to send emails from a web server to a Google apps for business email account and then be able to forward them automatically to an address somehow supplied through the original email.

The reason behind this is that when I try to send emails directly from my web server to people not in our Google Apps account, it automatically sends those emails to spam, and I just can't have that. When I send an email from my Google Apps email, it works fine. This is why I came up with the idea to automatically forward an email that came from the web server to the Google Apps and then to the customer.

The customer's email would somehow have to be supplied to the Google Apps account so that it can forward it properly. As a side note, I can send from my web server to the Google Apps but not to outside accounts.

Any help is very appreciated with this issue. If we can figure out how to forward or maybe even just send properly, that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm glad to know that you realized that the solution was to fix your server settings. Server setup is off-topic in Web Applications. Please follow the [tour](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn the ropes of this site and update your question to make to make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes it's possible to send emails to variable email addresses, but the use case solution is in another direction that is off-topic here.

## Alternatives for forwarding email messages to variable email addresses

1. Use Gmail filters. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en
2. Use Gmail API. See https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/
3. Use Google Apps Script. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/
4. Use email routing. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/77182?hl=en

Comment: Very interesting, sir. I will definitely look into the Gmail API and Google Apps Script. I'll count this as a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright never mind then. I have figured out how to make my Exchange server send properly to external emails and not get sent to spam. An SPF record is what I was looking for. Just threw one of those in my TXT records in my domain and I was all set.

On another note, the question still lies (for curiosity purposes), can you variably forward an email based on some information provided in the email?